# How do I access and perform operations on the "Web Thread"

Tags: ios, objective-c

We run almost our entire app on background threads to keep the UI clean and responsive, however when we load up full-screen HTML, we need to run it on the main thread, else we get the typical error "Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread." Obviously, loading this much data on the main thread results in a noticeable stutter. (Note that these are static, in-app assets that are delivered as HTML and that we render in-app with web views that don't actually access the web, just show local content.)

So, it tells me I can get the web lock either on the main thread or the "web thread"; is there any way to actually access that web thread and run this code on it so I can keep the UI responsive?

Comment: UIWebView, like many of its UIKit contemporaries, shouldn't be touched from the background. The thread you're describing actually *is* a background thread, but it's not exposed beyond the internal workings of UIWebViews. In short, when you load a request on a UIWebView, that request is implicitly loaded in the background/asynchronously.

Comment: I understand that the web thread is a background thread, but a UIWebView is certainly not implicitly loaded in a background thread, as is evidenced by the extremely obvious UI hiccup when doing a large load. I welcome you to test this yourself. It's easy enough to stick that same load in a background thread, as well, where it will crash a fair portion of the time, but when it doesn't crash there will be no UI blockage.

Comment: Yes, it is. Load a few UIWebViews with a few different URL requests and watch the threads rapidly multiply before your eyes. What you're seeing is the results of requests that are happening *in the background* be being handed back to the main thread for layout/drawing/rendering. I'm not saying UIWebViews (the object) load in the background. But the *requests* you load on them very much do.